# BigInteger NumberFormatException with hex input

Tags: java, biginteger, numberformatexception

I keep getting a java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString "9299ff"
Do I need to convert it to decimal to use multiply? I am not sure why I keep getting this error.

```
static BigInteger newP = new BigInteger("9299ff7061bff2d10d9b19653454453d6aed058b5331bea66a4b24e997aca5b6408e050f8e53d99be3f81f563a46b1dbfb51ff739c98f9ad38de2e2d48fdc6ba125604e15f6b76a03e3d64c09bfc7f5c635f80ca55747cf7d0f4839da6ceeb2c43e329021c6fd91f030251ef95180226d50dc1b4395471c69d60a676b263d2bb9f59884914db356bc6fe58d00a999c605a8cf6d246988531ffb79881501383dc092dcb97173c68d2548b7155006b31444cc7ab5c42b57128cd806d02c760e391");
static BigInteger newQ = new BigInteger("a3ec1a1cf64063fd97ad6a24e3509e6d04c36d5be75e3e567b4c713ee6bbbb3bbdcdfb6f89796a6e5d16624ccccff1d154a3b7e5d08a183be9b6e269031224f2d8e454541e22b6a71754a25385b5fdb1b54c69840d6336129d1f02bc39c155a849dfbed96bac2588a50b316499b84430b6104008852ba2b0c09601ca94aa591ff9f31fc6a8df338019e3bb83b5cad61a3bc76dede4d1224aed8c9d7883f8bbcb677164a2138592973af4dbd92bd9e7fcfcc4bbbf19e295bbb6ed14dc5c680311");
final static BigInteger newM = BigInteger.valueOf(65537);
static BigInteger newN = newP.multiply(newQ);


System.out.println(newN);
```

Comment: You need to specify the radix if it is different than 10, `BigInteger("yournumber", 16)`

Comment: Ask yourself this: If I write `new BigInteger("15")` how do you know that the base is 10, it could equally be base 70. You need to tell it that what you have there is base 16.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default radix is 10, you can specify the radix with [`BigInteger​(String val, int radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,int)), try:

```
BigInteger newP = new BigInteger("your input", 16);
```

Comment: you may also include the fact that the method OP uses defaults to radix 10.